# What is Local value serialization error in kafka?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I recently went through Confluent Kafka library in C# .net 4.7.2 framework version. But, many times I faced Local Value serialization error. Is this error is a generic one? or this error tells anything specifically? I'm not sure when will this error raises?

```
var rs = (RecordSchema)RecordSchema.Parse(@"{
""namespace"": ""Confluent.Kafka.Examples.AvroSpecific"",
""type"": ""record"",
""name"": ""ProduceConsumeUser2"",
""fields"": [
    {""name"": ""name"", ""type"": ""string""},
    {""name"": ""favorite_number"",  ""type"": [""int"", ""null""]},
    {""name"": ""favorite_color"", ""type"": [""string"", ""null""]}
]}");

   using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryConfig)){
   using (var genericProducer = new ProducerBuilder<string, GenericRecord>(producerConfig)
  .SetValueSerializer(new AvroSerializer<GenericRecord>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
  .Build())
{
    var genericRecord = new GenericRecord(rs);
    genericRecord.Add("name", "my name 2");
    genericRecord.Add("favorite_number", 44);
    genericRecord.Add("favorite_color", null);

    var message = new Message<string, GenericRecord>
    {
        Key = contentEventName,
        Value = genericRecord
    };
    Task.Run(() => genericProducer.ProduceAsync(contentEventName, message)).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}}
```

Error we get:

```
 "Error":{
  "Code":-161,
  "IsFatal":false,
  "Reason":"Local: Value serialization error",
  "IsError":true,
  "IsLocalError":true,
  "IsBrokerError":false
},
"Message":"Local: Value serialization error",
"Data":{ },
"InnerException":{
  "ClassName":"System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException",
  "Message":"A task was canceled.",
  "Data":null,
  "InnerException":null,
  "HelpURL":null,
  "StackTraceString":"   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.RestService.<ExecuteOnOneInstanceAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.RestService.<RequestAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.RestService.<RegisterSchemaAsync>d__18.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<RegisterSchemaAsync>d__21.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.GenericSerializerImpl.<Serialize>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.AvroSerializer`1.<SerializeAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at Confluent.Kafka.Producer`2.<ProduceAsync>d__52.MoveNext()",
  "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
  "RemoteStackIndex":0,
  "ExceptionMethod":"8\nThrowForNonSuccess\nmscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter\nVoid ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)",
  "HResult":-2146233029,
  "Source":"mscorlib",
  "WatsonBuckets":null
},
"StackTrace":"   at Confluent.Kafka.Producer`2.<ProduceAsync>d__52.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n  at LogEvent(String contentEventName, IDictionary`2 e, RecordSchemaName re)",
"HelpLink":null,
"Source":"Confluent.Kafka",
"HResult":-2146233088
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that is throwing the error?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt updated please have a look

Comment: Please try to refrain from adding remarks about whether your question is a duplicate. There is no way you can have searched through all 19.6M questions here to determine this. Moreover, readers want to know that you are open to receiving a duplicate notification for a question that you might have missed. Wait until you receive such remarks, examine a proposed duplicate thoroughly, and if you think the proposed duplicate does not cover your situation, edit your post to explain why. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I cannot be for certain. But I got to this page because I had the same exception details /issue...

*For me*, solving the issue was **making sure I had the correct credentials for the Schema Registry.** DOH! *Hope this helps for at least someone else!*

In my C# test using the Confulent.Kafka and Confluent.SchemaRegistry the  (username:password) are that exact syntax with the (:) colon in one string

```
string credentials ="MyUserName:mypassword";

var schemaRegistryConfig = new SchemaRegistryConfig()
    {
       Url = config.GetValue<string>("ConfluentCloud:SchemaRegistry:Url", string.Empty), 
       BasicAuthUserInfo = config.GetValue<string>("ConfluentCloud:SchemaRegistry:Credentials", string.Empty),
   };
                    
// no serializer required for string key 
using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryConfig))
```

... etc. etc.

Comment: This was also my problem -- thanks @ReidK